# What is a good AWS client?

Tags: amazon-s3

The web based AWS console seems so limited in what it can do. For example, to create a private stream distribution, you have to create CloudFront Origin Access Identity, create private content distribution, and modify ALC on the private objects, all through XML calls (WTF?). I really expect something so common to be integrated into their Console.

Is there a client smart enough that allows me to do simple tasks in simple ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure CloudFront Private Content with cloudberry freeware. http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/2010/03/how-to-configure-private-content-for.html

Answer (score 5):

Some options are:

1. [**ylastic**](http://ylastic.com/) - A web based tool that does automate many multi-step operations.
2. [**Cloudberry Explorer**](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx) - A Windows only client application
3. [**Bucket Explorer**](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/) - A cross platform client application

I'm not sure if these perform the tasks you need by they are worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, you should probably look for cloud management softwares. They are an additional layer on top of Amazon Web Services and leverage AWS API to offer automations tools like automated backups, auto-scaling, failover by default...

Ylastic was mentionned by Geoff, but you can try [Scalr](http://scalr.net) (disclaimer: I work there), RightScale or enStratus.

Answer (score 0):

I have felt this way too...but it seems the aws command line tools is the only options that I know..

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer: No! It is even hard to find a GUI to manage more than one aws product
And no one will put in effort to develop this as aws keep changing the API interface.
For me:
For stable aws service like S3, I use Cyberduck
And the rest of them, I write my own program to do it, it is more customized for my own need and not easy to make mistake (and help me to familiar with the api)